# pdfbox writing compressed object streams

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm merging multiple files, which originally have 19mb.

But the result is a total of 56mb. How can I make this final value approach the 19mb.
[EDIT]

```
public void concatena(InputStream anterior, InputStream novo, OutputStream saida, List<String> marcadores)
    throws IOException {
    PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
    pdfMerger.setDestinationStream(saida);
    PDDocument dest;
    PDDocument src;
    MemoryUsageSetting setupMainMemoryOnly = MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly();
    if (anterior != null) {                     
        dest = PDDocument.load(anterior, setupMainMemoryOnly);
        src = PDDocument.load(novo, setupMainMemoryOnly);
    } else {
        dest = PDDocument.load(novo, setupMainMemoryOnly);
        src = new PDDocument();
    }       
    int totalPages = dest.getNumberOfPages();   
    pdfMerger.appendDocument(dest, src);
    criaMarcador(dest, totalPages, marcadores);
    saida = pdfMerger.getDestinationStream();
    dest.save(saida);
    dest.close();
    src.close();
}
```

Sorry, I still do not know how to use stackoverflow very well. I'm trying to post the rest of the code but I'm getting an error

[Edit 2 - add criaMarcador method]

```
private void criaMarcador(PDDocument src, int numPaginas, List<String> marcadores) {
    if (marcadores != null && !marcadores.isEmpty()) {
        PDDocumentOutline documentOutline = src.getDocumentCatalog().getDocumentOutline();          
        if (documentOutline == null) {
            documentOutline = new PDDocumentOutline();
        }
        PDPage page;
        if (src.getNumberOfPages() == numPaginas) {
            page = src.getPage(0);
        } else {
            page = src.getPage(numPaginas);
        }
        PDOutlineItem bookmark = null;
        PDOutlineItem pai = null;
        String etiquetaAnterior = null;
        for (String etiqueta : marcadores) {                
            bookmark = bookmark(pai != null ? pai : documentOutline, etiqueta);
            if (bookmark == null) {
                if (etiquetaAnterior != null && !etiquetaAnterior.equals(etiqueta) && pai == null) {
                    pai = bookmark(documentOutline, etiquetaAnterior);
                }
                bookmark = new PDOutlineItem();
                bookmark.setTitle(etiqueta);
                if (marcadores.indexOf(etiqueta) == marcadores.size() - 1) {
                    bookmark.setDestination(page);
                }
                if (pai != null) {
                    pai.addLast(bookmark);
                    pai.openNode();
                } else {
                    documentOutline.addLast(bookmark);
                }
            } else {
                pai = bookmark;
            }
            etiquetaAnterior = etiqueta;
        }   
        src.getDocumentCatalog().setDocumentOutline(documentOutline);           
    }       
}

private PDOutlineItem bookmark(PDOutlineNode outline, String etiqueta) {             
    PDOutlineItem current = outline.getFirstChild();
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.getTitle().equals(etiqueta)) {
            return current;
        }
        bookmark(current, etiqueta);
        current = current.getNextSibling();
    }
    return current;
}
```

[Edit 3]Here is the code used for testing

```
public class PDFMergeTeste {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if (args.length == 1) {
        PDFMergeTeste teste = new PDFMergeTeste();
        teste.executa(args[0]);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Argumento tem que ser diretorio contendo arquivos .pdf com nomeclatura no padrão Autos");
    }
}

private void executa(String diretorioArquivos) throws IOException {
    File[] listFiles = new File(diretorioArquivos).listFiles((pathname) -> 
            pathname.getName().endsWith(".pdf") || pathname.getName().endsWith(".PDF"));
    List<File> lista = Arrays.asList(listFiles);
    lista.sort(Comparator.comparing(File::lastModified));
    PDFMerge merge = new PDFMerge();
    InputStream anterior = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream saida = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    for (File file : lista) {
        List<String> marcadores = marcadores(file.getName());           
        InputStream novo = new FileInputStream(file);           
        merge.concatena(anterior, novo, saida, marcadores);                     
        anterior = new ByteArrayInputStream(saida.toByteArray());
    }
    try (OutputStream pdf = new FileOutputStream(pathDestFile)) {
        saida.writeTo(pdf);
    }


}
private List<String> marcadores(String name) {
    String semExtensao = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(".pdf"));
    return Arrays.asList(semExtensao.split("_"));       
}
```

}

Comment: Please share the files. And tell your version.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr https://www.dropbox.com/sh/elbjegfykxux6wf/AAC8SMU6-7_sAPS7yqgZkDn0a?dl=0

Comment: @ArthurMenezes Those files are samples of files you have to merge?

Comment: Still waiting for the version. And the files from the link are smaller than 100KB. No 19MB there.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr The shared files are a subset of the files cited in the post

Comment: @mkl  Yes, they are samples.

Comment: Your question is about MB. Your sample files are not. What are you expecting of the sample files, and what happens instead? And I'm still waiting for the PDFBox version number.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Of course, sorry, the version is 2.0.4. My question is why PDFMergerUtility is increasing the final file size

Comment: I just merged the files "00002 - Distribuição - dia 10.11.2016.pdf" and "00041 - Digitação de Documentos - dia 10.11.2016.pdf" using your code. The source file sizes are 65706 bytes and 12436 bytes. The result file size is 78309 bytes. Thus, in contrast to your claim `PDFMergerUtility` does not increase the size much beyond the sum of the sources, at least not for the example files you shared. Of course, as you did not provide that `criaMarcador(dest, totalPages, marcadores)` method, I dropped that call. Is that method of yours probably doing the harm?

Comment: @mkl sorry. I edited my post and added the rest of the code

Comment: Ok, with your additional methods I can make the result file size grow. E.g. if I use `marcadores = Collections.nCopies(2000, "Test")` in the example mentioned above, the result file size grows from the 78309 bytes before to 191239. Thus, is that method of yours probably doing the harm in your case, too? In that case, by the way, it obviously not the `PDFMergerUtility` which makes your files explode.

Comment: @mkl Any idea why this?

Comment: @mkl I commented the call of the method criaMarcadores and the result continues with disproporcinal size. I will edit the post and include the used code that calls the concatena method. Includes all files used for testing in the dropbox, follow the link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/elbjegfykxux6wf/AAC8SMU6-7_sAPS7yqgZkDn0a?dl=0

Comment: Ah, the error is in the `executa` method. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the `executa` method:

```
InputStream anterior = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream saida = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
for (File file : lista) {
    List<String> marcadores = marcadores(file.getName());           
    InputStream novo = new FileInputStream(file);           
    merge.concatena(anterior, novo, saida, marcadores);                     
    anterior = new ByteArrayInputStream(saida.toByteArray());
}
```

Your `ByteArrayOutputStream saida` is re-used in each loop but it is not cleared in-between. Thus, it contains

- after processing file 1:

  - file 1
- after processing file 2:

  - file 1
  - concatenation of file 1 and file 2
- after processing file 3: file 1

  - file 1
  - concatenation of file 1 and file 2
  - concatenation of file 1 and file 2 and file 3
- after processing file 4:

  - file 1
  - concatenation of file 1 and file 2
  - concatenation of file 1 and file 2 and file 3
  - concatenation of file 1 and file 2 and file 3 and file 4

(Actually this only works because PDFBox tries to be nice and fixes broken input files under the hood as these concatenations of files strictly speaking are broken and PDFBox doesn't need to be able to parse them.)

You can fix this by clearing `saida` at the start of each iteration:

```
InputStream anterior = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream saida = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
for (File file : lista) {
    saida.reset();
    List<String> marcadores = marcadores(file.getName());           
    InputStream novo = new FileInputStream(file);           
    merge.concatena(anterior, novo, saida, marcadores);                     
    anterior = new ByteArrayInputStream(saida.toByteArray());
}
```

With your original method the result size for your inputs is nearly 26 MB, with the fixed method it is about 5 MB, and that latter size approximately represents the sum of the sizes of the input files.